# fast insertion of millions of records into database and search

Tags: .net, database

I am coding in VB 2008

Suppose in some way I have millions of strings.
These have to be inserted "one-time" in the database with only 1 table having only 1 column.
And then later at some point of time, I need to search the database for a particular string.

Q1. how can I make the insertion faster?

Its a one-time inserting, ie, I need to insert it just one time. No need of updating.
I tried dividing the set of strings in to five and use 5 threads to simultaneously insert the data. [RAM and CPU usage are don't care conditions]. But it still its not effective.

Q2. How can I making the searching faster?

Right now i just query the DB like

```
select column1 from table1 where column1 like 'something'
```

I heard there are better searching techniques.
Do you think you could suggest the best possible technique for searching in my database?

Q3. Currently I am using ADODC. [mdb file]

should i migrate to MySQL, SQLite or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using LIKE? Do you intend to support wildcards? What sort of wildcard queries will you make?

Comment: More clients (threads) will only be faster if the RDMBS (and SQL operation) can handle it ;-) Make sure you are only committing ONCE at the end.

Comment: If its a one time import; why not use Access import feature?

Comment: I'm confused. This is tagged .NET but you mention ADODC which is a VB6/VBA thing. And it looks like you are using MS-Access. The answers to all of these questions are highly database specific so you might want to clarify if you are using MS-Access or not.

Comment: @MarkByers the user would be adding the wildcards.

Comment: @pst I don't know if ADODC is multithreaded or not...

Comment: @xQbert: actually the user would be providing the data...

Comment: @MatthewMartin Pardon me, but i didn't knew that...
considering my situation, can you suggest databases?

Comment: For performance, use MS-SQL SQLExpress (it's free), for import use SqlBulkCopy (it's fast and straightforward but MSSQL only), for fast queries add indexes, for fast inserts, remove the indexes.  MS-Access is for small quantities of data and a small number of users.

Answer (score 4):

Q1: You can use the [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class to insert lots of data in one table.

Q2: Make sure you have proper indexes on the columns you search. If you search with `LIKE '%searchterm` (with `%` at the beginning) you can improve search performance if you use full text search.

Comment: isn't the SqlBulkCopy class used for copying bulk data from one source to another? I think I should have mentioned that user provides the data to be inserted, and that will generally won't be a source. thanks for the reply!

Comment: You can put all the entered user strings in a DataTable and use the [`WriteToServer(DataTable)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx) overload. Or you can implement the [`IDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx) interface.